# Activity name is not set to a valid class name

Tags: java, android-studio

No puedo crear nueva Activity me sale

> Activity name is not set to a valid class name
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No pongas espacios en el "Activity Name". "Activity Name" es el nombre de la clase de la actividad que se va a crear y **los nombres de las clases no pueden contener espacios en blanco**.

Como puedes ver en esta animación, si añades espacios en blanco es cuando recibes el error y desactiva el botón de "Finalizar"; y si quitas esos espacios en blanco, se activa el botón y te deja continuar sin problemas:

[image: animación que muestra como los espacios en blanco causan el error]

Comment: con o sin espacio me sale lo mismo